# how to join two db tables and cross reference another

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm trying to figure out an efficient way to join tables and cross reference with another table, with the reference looking to check that each record found in the join does not have a field which exists in the other table.

This is what I have so far - I somehow need to be able to make sure that each record's reg_no is not present in the buyers table (basically before an automated email is sent). Grateful for any pointers - anything that saves me having to iterate through each record and do an individual lookup!

```
SELECT * FROM (`owners`, `buyers`) 
 JOIN `records` ON (`records`.`pa_no` = `owners`.`contact_no`) 
 WHERE email <> "" AND `buyers`.reg_no <> `records`.reg_no
```

Comment: Are you trying to exclude records with duplicate reg_nos from your query, or identify duplicates so that they can then be removed?

Comment: The former - I want to send an email to those who do not already have a reg_no in the buyers table.

Comment: I think you might be going about this the wrong way.  `records.reg_no` smells like it should be a foreign key to `buyers.reg_no`.  If that's the case, allowing the record to even be created without having a corresponding buyer seems like bad design.

Comment: @Mark Peters - true, the records table is linked to buyers by reg_no, although the records table is only ever used as a reference, whereas the buyers table interacts with the application - when buyers are registering, they can only register if they enter a reg_no which corresponds with a reg_no which exists in the records table - i do a server side check at this stage to make sure they are providing a valid reg_no. Not sure if that makes any more sense...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
select * from `owners`
join `records` ON (`records`.`pa_no` = `owners`.`contact_no`)
WHERE email <> ""
and not exists (select reg_no from `buyers` 
                where `buyers`.reg_no = `records`.reg_no)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like a LEFT JOIN?

```
SELECT r.reg_no
  FROM records as r LEFT JOIN buyers as b ON (r.reg_no = b.reg_no)
  WHERE b.reg_no IS NULL
```

A LEFT JOIN between tables A and B will give you a table with at least one row for every row in A. With a normal JOIN, rows in A where the associated row in B was not found will be omitted; for a LEFT JOIN these rows will be included, but all of B's columns will simply have NULL values. So you can test a field that can never be NULL (like the primary key or foreign key): if it's NULL then you're certain this row (of A) do not have an associated row in B.

And if I understand your question correctly, this is what you want -- a table of all the rows in `records` (together with `owner` information) that has no associated `buyer` information.

So, you could either use something like the above as a subquery or view, and JOIN it normally with `owner`, or you could do it all in one (I believe MySQL should be intelligent enough to optimize it so these approaches are equivalent):

```
SELECT * -- though probably you want to specify what columns you want
  FROM (owners o JOIN records r ON (o.contact_no=r.pa_no))
    LEFT JOIN buyers b ON (r.reg_no=b.reg_no)
  WHERE email<>'' AND b.reg_no IS NULL
```

(I'm just typing it in as I think it might work, I haven't tested this. Please correct me if I'm wrong.)

Comment: That `ON` clause probably doesn't make much sense if `b.reg_no` is NULL.

Comment: It makes perfect sense. It's a LEFT JOIN, so the only way that b.reg_no will be NULL (assuming it's a NOT NULL column) is if the join didn't find a match. It's an alternate method of looking for non-existence of a row.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - I now have a couple of different ways of achieving this, very helpful

Comment: Oh, the difference an 's' can make, hehe.